# Exporting FBX with textures

Tags: export, .fbx

Blender 4.0

I am a noob when it comes to Blender. I've used other 3D apps for decades. I'm having problems exporting FBX files that include texture data. I have a Google 3D Tile mesh generated using BLOSM. Love this addon. The materials are set to Principled BSDF. I have tried using the default FBX exporter, making sure Path Mode is set to Copy with Embed Textures enabled. I have also purchased and used Better FBX Exporter. No matter what I do, I do not get an FBX with textures. I can export a default cube with textures. But the Google 3D Tiles mesh refuses to play nice. The mesh has a gazillion materials, each with their own texture. When I import the FBX back into Blender all of the materials have the same texture. I'm really hoping there is a checkbox somewhere that I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Mesh
[image]

FBX export settings

[image]

FBX imported back into Blender.
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures